# Does a lack of windows protect against shockwave of a nuclear attack?

Tags: nuclear-physics, shock-waves

I know that one of the dangers of a nuclear attack is the shockwave which compresses the air and can cause a pulmonary embolism in creatures in the area of effect. Is the shockwave directional in effect?

In other words, lets say your building is on the outskirts of a city and is built so that all the windows face AWAY from the city and only thick, concrete walls face the city side.

Will this protect the occupants from the shockwave of an explosion over the city or will the shockwave wash over the building and then go "backwards" through the windows?

Comment: On a side note, a lack of windows means that there isn't any glass that could be broken from the shockwave. Flying glass could conceivably cause many injuries, even far away from the main area of destruction.

Comment: Less windows and more thick concrete walls will definitely provide more protection than more windows. But we still add windows anyway because we like to be able to see outside and people on the windowless side wouldn't be very happy

Answer (score 1):

The direction of propagation of a shock wave does matter. However, a shock wave can diffract and refract, i.e., it propagates not just along the line-of-sight and can penetrate through concrete walls, so it can enter a building through windows in a wall of a building that does not face the explosion, and it can penetrate concrete walls of the building, although typically the diffracted and refracted waves will have a significantly lower amplitude than the incident wave. You may google "shock wave diffraction" and "shock wave refraction".

Answer (score 0):

The short and simple answer is no.

The more important thing to worry about in nuclear explosions is the heat.  If you are close enough to worry about the shock wave, you are likely to be exposed to extreme heat.  The center of thermonuclear explosions is well over one million degrees and the fireball from large hydrogen bombs can be more than a mile in diameter.

So I would be more concerned with the heat and radiation (if inside, then radiation from neutrons) than the shock/blast wave.

Answer (score 0):

A Human can survive much higher transient over pressures than can buildings. The problem with windows is flying glass. In a lot of terrorist attacks in cities windows being blown in  is a major source of casualties. That's why in the UK during WW2 many people had either heavy curtains or tape over the windows.